# how to detect collision between a circle and a rectangle without using physics library in unity(since it is not allowed for this homework)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to write codes to detect collision between cannon balls and lines in a mountain.  I have a minimum bounding circle around the cannon ball.
the mountain is drawn using line render and I tried to make a rectangular box around each of the line segment that make up the mountain. Then I want  to have an algorithm to detect when a circle collide with the mountain. But I'm not sure how to draw the rectangle around the lines of the mountain.

I had an algorithm before that doesn't draw rectangle around the line segments of the mountain. It checks instead if the circle hits the line. Please see my codes below, there, transform means the canon ball object:

```
public void CheckForTouchingMountain()
{
    Vector2[] slopeAndInt = mountain.gameObject.GetComponent<DrawMountain>().GetSlopeAndIntercept();
    for(int i=0;i<slopeAndInt.Length;i++)
    {
        if(transform.position.y-slopeAndInt[i].x*transform.position.x-slopeAndInt[i].y<=0f)
        {
            velocity.y = velocity.y-2* (slopeAndInt[i].x * transform.position.x + slopeAndInt[i].y);
            velocity.x = -(2 / 3) * velocity.x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity uses [Box2D](https://box2d.org/) as its 2D physics engine, and it's open source.

Comment: But I am not allowed to use the physics library for this homework. How can I do it without using the physics library?